# Comparing Two Dictionaries Key Values and Returning the Value If Match

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a beginner to Python, but I've been trying this syntax and I cannot figure it out -- which was been really baffling.

```
crucial = {'eggs': '','ham': '','cheese': ''}
dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}

if crucial.keys() in dishes.keys():
    print dishes[value]
```

What I want to do is -- if crucial has a key (in this case, `eggs`) in the dishes, it will return `2`. It seems simple enough, but I believe I must be messing some type of syntax somewhere. If someone could guide me a little, that would be greatly appreciated.

The real dictionaries I'm comparing with is about 150 keys long, but I'm hoping this code is simple enough.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to iterate over the keys in crucial and compare each one against the dishes keys. So a directly modified version of your code.

```
for key in crucial.keys():
    if key in dishes.keys():
        print(dishes[key])
```

It could be better stated as (no need to specify .keys):

```
for key in crucial:
    if key in dishes:
        print(dishes[key])
```

Comment: keys() is not necessary in this case, for default, iteration in a dictionary is enough. "for key in crucial.keys()" equals to "for key in crucial"

Comment: You're correct, and a list comprehension is the best option, however I thought an explicit example would be helpful for a Python beginner.

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful! I'm reading through the list comprehension now to learn a little bit more ...

Comment: You're welcome! List comprehension is definitely the preferred way to do something like this so you can't go wrong reading up on it.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Python 3, the `keys` method of dictionaries follows the `set` interface. That means you can do an intersection of the keys of the two dictionaries using the `&` operator.

```
for key in crucial.keys() & dishes.keys():
    print(dishes[key])
```

Or if you need a list of the values:

```
result = [dishes[key] for key in crucial.keys() & dishes.keys()]
```

In Python 2 you could manage the same thing by explicitly creating sets (perhaps from the `iterkeys` generator), but probably it would be better to simply do a loop over the keys, like several of the other answer suggest.

Here's a variation on the loop that I don't think I've seen anyone else do. The outer loop gets both the keys and values from the `dishes` dict, so you don't need to separately look up the value by key.

```
for key, value in dishes.iteritems(): # use items() in Python 3
    if key in crucial:
        print value
```

Comment: Strange how this answer is neglected. Tried it. Works great and has changed the way I think about writing certain types of code.

Answer (score 2):

using list comprehension is good

```
[ dishes[x] for x in crucial if dishes.has_key(x) ]
```

or ,as per gnibbler:

```
[ dishes[x] for x in crucial if x in dishes ]
```

this expression will iterate crucial every key in crucial, if key in dishes, it will return the value of same key in dishes , finally, return a list of all match values.

or , you can use this way, (set (crucial) & set(dishes)) return common keys of both set, then iterate this set and return the values in dishes .

```
[ dishes[x] for x in set (crucial) & set(dishes) ]
```

Comment: `has_key` is deprecated. Please use `x in dishes` instead

Comment: Or even `[dishes[x] for x in set(crucial).intersection(dishes)]` to shave off a whopping 70ns :)

Answer (score 0):

`has_key()` has been removed in Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Instead, you can use:

```
[dishes[key] for key in crucial.keys() if key in dishes]
```

The method used here is called list comprehension. You can read about it here:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already familiar with Python's REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop  --  that thing where you type in code, press enter and it immediately evaluates), that would be a good tool here.

So lets start breaking down your code.

```
crucial = {'eggs': '','ham': '','cheese': ''}
dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
```

Simple enough.  Though I note you do not have any values in the `crucials` dictionary.  I am not sure if that is an abbreviation for you example or if you are simply only caring about the keys.  If you are only caring about the keys, then I assume you are using a dictionary for the sake of ensuring uniqueness.  In that case, you should check out the [`set` data structure](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Example:

```
crutial = set(['cheese', 'eggs', 'ham'])
```

Continuing on we have

```
if crucial.keys() in dishes.keys():
```

here you are using the [`in` comparison operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in).  Example:

```
5 in [5, 4] #True
3 in [5, 4] #False
```

If we evaluate `crucial.keys()` and `dishes.keys()` we get

```
 >>> crucial.keys()
 ['cheese', 'eggs', 'ham']
 >>> dishes.keys()
 ['eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage', 'spam']
```

so during execution your code evaluates as

```
 ['cheese', 'eggs', 'ham'] in ['eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage', 'spam']
```

which returns `False` because the value `['eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage']` (which is a list) is not in the list `['eggs', 'bacon', 'sausage', 'spam']` (in fact there are no lists within that list, only strings).

Thus you are evaluating as

```
if False:
    print dishes[value] #note value is not defined.
```

It rather looks like you have mixed/confused the `in` operator which returns a boolean and the for iterator (`for item in collection`).  There is a syntax for this sort of thing.  It is called [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which you can find samples of in @ShawnZhang and @kmad's answers.  You can think of it as a terse way to filter and modify (map) a collection, returning a list as a result.  I do not want to get too in-depth there or I will end up in an introduction to functional programming.

Your other option is to use the `for .. in` iteration and `in` operators separately.  This is the solution @timc gave. Such solutions are probably a more familiar or easier for beginners.  It clearly separates the behavior of iterating and filtering.  It is also more like what would be written in other programming languages that do not have an equivalent to list comprehensions.  Those who work in Python a lot would probably favor the comprehension syntax.

Comment: vossad01, I appreciate the response. Your explanation I saved ... and is a bit more apparent as to why it wasn't working with my trial and error efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import operator
from collections import Counter

def mio(si, ti):
    si = Counter(s)
    ti = Counter(t)
    if operator.eq(si, ti):
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
crucial = {'eggs': '','ham': '','cheese': ''}
dishes = {'eggs': 2, 'sausage': 1, 'bacon': 1, 'spam': 500}
for key in set(dishes.keys()) & set(crucial.keys()):
    print dishes[key]
```

Similarly, you can have `set(dishes.keys()) - set(crucial.keys())` , `set(dishes.keys()) | set(crucial.keys())` , or `set(dishes.keys()) ^ set(crucial.keys())`.

Comment: in this way, you can have set(dishes.keys()) - set(crucial.keys()) , set(dishes.keys()) | set(crucial.keys()) , or set(dishes.keys()) ^ set(crucial.keys())